# "message": "(#200) If posting to a group, requires app being installed in the group

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've created a test group and a test bot:

[image]

I own the group so I should be able to create an app that posts to the group.

The app is in developer mode. If I put it in production mode, I can't find  it in the apps   list:

[image]

How can I install the app to the group if it doesn't appears in the apps list? Because it already have "publish_to_groups" permission

To access that list I'm going to facebook group page -> group settings -> apps -> add apps

Comment: have you got any solution, i stuck at the same place

Comment: I have had the exact same problem for 4 weeks now when everything was working perfectly before.
It asks me to add the application to the group, but I can't do it.
And to get the right `publish_to_groups`, I think there is now no other choice than to make a submission of the app to Facebook.
The only problem is that you have to make a video showing the application working.
It's the snake that dies on the tail.

Comment: Any solutions to this?